# my header disappears when using maketitle

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\inputencoding{latin1}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacitex}



% try this package for ʾ ʿ
% \usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% package for times new roman font
\usepackage{times}
% package for different shapes 
%\usepackage{amssymb}
% single space or double space lines
\usepackage{setspace}
    %\singlespacing
    \doublespacing

% header 
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{ \Author \\MyName\\Assignment}
\rhead{\itshape \today}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% page number 
\rfoot{\thepage}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\topskip=18pt

\maketitle{My title }




\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! That is usual behaviour, because you would double informations contained in the title page in the header. For good typography the header is supposed to be printed on page 2 ff. BTW: is `\usepackage{covington}` a special font?How do you compile? I'm not sure that `\usepackage{fontspec}` is right here! Depends on what `covington` should do ...  Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: the covington is for special arabic symbols such ... but this is not related to the title that let the header disappears

Comment: @Moha Kurt said that it is usual behaviour. Doubling information is very bad.

Answer (score 1):

The `\maketitle` macro -- note that it does *not* an argument -- implicitly issues the instruction

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
```

The `plain` page style is, well, "plain": nothing fancy, just the page number gets printed centered in the bottom margin. That's the issue you're complaining about, right?

To avoid this outcome, you could either the issue the instruction `\thispagestyle{fancy}` immediately after `\maketitle`, or you could add the instruction `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}` in the preamble, immediately after setting up the properties of the `fancy` page style.

Incidentally, I wouldn't recommend that you use either of these two solutions. It's usually preferable to keep the title page nice and simple -- and to hold off with any page decorations until after the titlepage is typeset.

---

Some additional remarks about your code. (a) If you load the `fontspec` package, you should *not* be loading the `inputenc` package, and you certainly shouldn't load the `times` font package. Instead, issue an instruction such as `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` (or whatever your preferred main text font may be). (b) As already mentioned, `\maketitle` does not take an argument, and your code snippet is missing `\title` and `\author` instructions. (c) How is `\Author` defined?

A compilable and cleaned-up version of your example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % not "\usepackage{times}"

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacitex}

\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\let\Author\author % ??

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\Author\\MyName\\Assignment}
\rhead{\itshape\today}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} % <-- new

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\thispagestyle{fancy}  % instead of "\fancypagestyle{plain}{}"

\clearpage

Once upon a time \dots
\end{document}
```