header with logo in latex article page not working
I found the following Create custom header with LaTeX
but when adding author and title, I loose the logo and all the header.
Here is my code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[headheight=55pt]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{%
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} \hfill 
\parbox[b]{5cm}{\centering Latex World Learning\\
very neat\\ no irritating eyes} \hfill 
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%other packages below this line
%\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{graphicx,color}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{balance}

\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{keywords---}} #1}

\title{Guidelines for authors}

\author[1,*]{First A.}
\author[2]{Second A.}
\author[1]{Third A.}
\affil[1]{UNLP}
\affil[2]{CONICET}
\affil[*]{\textbf{corresponding author}: First A. (e-mail: author@unlp.edu.ar).}
\date{}
\begin{document}

%\centering
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here. No images are alowed. The maximum number of words is XXXX.
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}


\keywords{one, two, three, four}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

%% \bibitem{label}
%% Text of bibliographic item

\bibitem{}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

Can you help me on this?
The idea is something like:


With \maketitle, there is not header on the first page of an article. It's the default page style. Add \lipsum[2-8] before \begin{thebibliography}{00} and you will see what you wait on page 2 and 3.

You are right. This means I cannot add a Logo and header on an article page? Because the idea is that everybody submit an abstract with a template that includes the logo

Welcome to TeX.SE! Sounds a little bit for me for an xy-problem. Can you please explain your idea better in your question?

I need an article page (with work title, abstract,etc) I've just added a picture in the question.

The first page uses the style plain, not the fancy style when you uses \maketitle. Workaround: after \pagestyle{fancy} in your preamble, add \fancypagestyle{plain}{...} and instead of "..." replace it by the copied definition \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics... \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}. So you have a solution.

Thanks @quark67 It is working! the only thing is that I had to change "the bibliography" by a section because it adds the word "References" to the upper right of the page...

See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233728/how-to-use-fancyhdr-and-maketitle-concurrently, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477807/my-header-disappears-when-using-maketitle
